# Buffer data changed after sending to client

Tags: node.js, express, h.264

I'm trying to live stream a video from my backend to clients, by sending H264 frames.
I tried sending the frames with Socket.io, as well as returning them in a response stream, however in both cases the data seems to change when sent and I'm confused why.

This is an example buffer for one of the frames from the video, logged by my backend:

```
<Buffer 00 00 00 01 41 fc 01 3c 68 df 38 79 7f a0 10 26 e7 af f4 02 04 dc f5 fe 80 40 9b 9e bf d0 08 13 73 d7 fa 01 02 6e 7a ff 40 20 4d cf 5f e8 04 09 b9 eb ... 78 more bytes>
```

but the client-side looks like this

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 65, 252, 1, 60, 104, 223, 56, 121, 127, 160, 16, 38, 231, 175, …]
```

The first four values are always correct but after this the buffer should have the value `41` instead of `65` and so on...

The buffer itself is sent as part of a stringifed object which looks like this

```js
res.write(
  JSON.stringify({
    type: "frame",
    pts: <BigInt>,
    keyframe: <Boolean>
    data: <Buffer>
  })
)
```

Then on my client I convert it back using

```js
fetch('url').then((res) => {
  if (!res.ok) throw res;
  if (res.status == 204) return;
  res.body.pipeThrough(new TextDecoderStream()) //buffer to utf-8
     .pipeThrough(new TransformStream({
        transform(chunk, controller) {
          const lines = chunk.replace(/}{/g, "};{").split(";"); //split string to json's
            for (const line of lines) {
              controller.enqueue(line);
            }  
          },
       }))
       .pipeThrough(new TransformStream({ //utf-8 to json
         transform(line, controller) {
           if (line) {
             controller.enqueue(JSON.parse(line, reviver))  //reviver for pts/BigInt
           }
         }
       }))
       .pipeThrough(new TransformStream({
         transform(packet, controller) {
           if (packet.type != "config") {
             packet.data = buffer.Buffer.from(packet.data) //object to Buffer ("buffer" from browserify )
           }
         }
       }))
       .pipeTo(decoder.writable) //json to video
)
```

Is this a conversion issue or just normal behaviour?

It's currently the only problem I can think of, as my decoder does not show errors or the video/frames.

Comment: It seems like the server buffer is in hex format (base 16 number), but the client receives it as number (base 10). To prove it: `parseInt('41', 16) === 65` and `parseInt('fc', 16) === 252`. Just adding a logic to handle this format conversion should fix it.

Comment: @Tabea Why use `JSON.stringify` instead of just making a standard Object? That might keep your buffer data unchanged.

Comment: @VC.One Unfortunately when I try to send the object without stringify, the application crashes and I have no idea why... especially since I get different error messages and none of them has anything to do with the actual sending process.

Comment: @Tabea Ok no worries. To a computer these are different ways of writing the same value so the buffer array should still work.

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is the data managed by your buffer is set on base16 or hexadecimal numbers, on the other hand, JSON.stringify always return the data in decimal format (base10). If you want to have the same data went frontend receives it, you need to use the replacer parameter on stringify function.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It still only works on my backend though. In the replacer I create a hex string on my buffer by doing `Buffer.from(value).toString('hex')`. If I convert this right back on my backend using `Buffer.from(packet.data, 'hex')` I get the same buffer. In my client, using the same method I still get a decimal buffer though. Any ideas?

Comment: You can use: 


`JSON.stringify(obj, (key, value) => {
  if( typeof value === 'number'){
    return '0x' + value.toString(16)
  }
  return value
})`